# When I add Android permission <user-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" /> to manifest, why this AATP error?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm working on a Android app using Kotlin, and when I run the app with the below manifest, the app runs...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.projectX_01">

    <!-- needed -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <!-- not sure if needed -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ProjectX_01">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

However, when I add the (one line) permission to modify my audio settings, it goes kaput

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.projectX_01">

    <!-- needed -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <!-- not sure if needed -->
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ProjectX_01">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and I get "Android resource linking failed" with the following error:
... app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in `<manifest>`.

Any ideas what's causing this?

PS:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask for permission

```
Dexter.withContext(this)
.withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
.withListener(new PermissionListener() {
    @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {/* ... */}
    @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {/* ... */}
    @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {/* ... */}
}).check();
```

here's the [library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)